# Adding JavaScript To Shopify Store

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I have made a custom script like this:

```
<script src="../full_path/script.js"></script>
<script>
 my_function('init');
</script>
```

Here,
my_function is a function which is present in script.js file.

Also, I would like to enable this function for all pages on the store.

(PS: I went through the ScriptTag shopify api, but could not figure it out)

Please help how do i do it ?

Comment: How are you adding these 4 lines on your website. What issue are you facing? Explain in detail please.

Comment: Unless you answer @HymnZzy question, most likely no one is going to be able to help!